# I am trying to build NodeJS and ExpressJS backend service and got lots of module not found error

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, node-modules

I am trying to build NodeJS and ExpressJS backend service and got lots of module not found error.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node-assignment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "npm run build && NODE_ENV=production node build/bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "Het Patel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.9.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack": "^5.82.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./server.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
};
```

**Project File Structure**

[image]

**Console Screenshot**
[image: Console Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals)
 to exclude node modules in Webpack. You don't need to bundle node modules in the `bundle.js` output file for Nodejs server-side applications. Nodejs application will retrieve these external dependencies at runtime via `require()`

> When bundling with Webpack for the backend - you usually don't want to bundle its `node_modules` dependencies. This library creates an externals function that ignores `node_modules` when bundling in Webpack.

Besides, we don't want to bundle the built-in modules like `fs`, `path`, so we should use [`externalsPresets: { node: true }`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externalspresets) option to exclude them.

For Webpack v5

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './server.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  externalsPresets: { node: true },
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
};
```

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started'))
```

Run `npm run build` script:

```bash
> webpack

asset bundle.js 328 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main)
./server.js 195 bytes [built] [code generated]
external "express" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.82.0 compiled successfully in 321 ms
```

**Output**

`dist/bundle.js`:

```js
(()=>{var e={860:e=>{"use strict";e.exports=require("express")}},r={};function s(t){var o=r[t];if(void 0!==o)return o.exports;var n=r[t]={exports:{}};return e[t](n,n.exports,s),n.exports}(()=>{const e=s(860),r=e();r.use(e.json()),r.get("/",((e,r)=>{r.sendStatus(200)})),r.listen(3e3,(()=>console.log("Server started")))})()})();
```

Run it:

```bash
⚡  node dist/bundle.js 
Server started
```

Comment: What does it mean by -- external "express" 42 bytes [built] [code generated] ? Even when we have nodeExternals() to bypass node_modules.

Comment: @laxman Please ask a new question instead of asking in the comment